Do there exist any non-trivial "memoryless" interpolation functions
We shall define a memoryless interpolation function as a function $f:\Bbb{R}^2\times[0,1]\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ which satisfies the following $3$ properties,
$\begin{array}{lc}
1)& f(x,y,0)=x\\[2ex]
2)&f(x,y,1)=y\\[2ex]
3)&f\left(f(x,y,t_0),y,\frac{t-t_0}{1-t_0}\right)=f(x,y,t)&\forall t\geq t_0,t_0\in[0,1]
\end{array}$
One trivial solution is $f(x,y,t)=x+(y-x)t$ (i.e. linear interpolation), my question is, are there any other solutions?
We can see by differentiating $(3)$ first by $t$ and then by $t_0$ and then letting $t_0=0$ that any such $f$ must satisfy the P.D.E,
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial t}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+(t-1)\cdot\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0\tag{*}$$
As far as I can tell all solutions of $(*)$ are of the form,
$$f(x,y,t)=A(x,y)+\int_0^tB(x,y)e^{\int_0^t\frac{r(x,y,t)}{1-t}\text{d}t}\text{d}t$$
where $r(x,y,t)=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial t}(x,y,t)$
(Although it is not clear that any such equation satisfies $(*)$, and I suspect it may not be true that they all do)
However solutions to $(*)$ only locally satisfy $(3)$ and need not satisfy it globally. I am unsure how to proceed.

If $f(x,y,t)$ is such a function, so does $g(x,y,t) = \psi^{-1}(f(\psi(x),\psi(y),t))$ for any bijection $\psi$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

@achillehui Thank you so much. That is sort of obvious now that I see it, I do still wonder if it is possible to fully classify all such functions.

Let $v = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$, then the PDE becomes $(t-1)v_t + vv_x = -v$, which can be solved via the method of characteristics
